# Attribute value must be constant but when the @Layout(R.layout.tinder_card_view) is removed the error disappears in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml

@Layout(R.layout.tinder_card_view) this is not showing instead it saying "Attribute value must be constant".

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.heartdating.heart.R;
import com.mindorks.placeholderview.SwipePlaceHolderView;
import com.mindorks.placeholderview.annotations.Layout;
import com.mindorks.placeholderview.annotations.Resolve;
import com.mindorks.placeholderview.annotations.View;
import com.mindorks.placeholderview.annotations.swipe.SwipeCancelState;
import com.mindorks.placeholderview.annotations.swipe.SwipeIn;
import com.mindorks.placeholderview.annotations.swipe.SwipeInState;
import com.mindorks.placeholderview.annotations.swipe.SwipeOut;
import com.mindorks.placeholderview.annotations.swipe.SwipeOutState;

@Layout(R.layout.tinder_card_view) *//here is where the problem is i can't get the XML file from layout directory*
public class TinderCard {

    @View(R.id.profileImageView)
    private ImageView profileImageView;

    @View(R.id.nameAgeTxt)
    private TextView nameAgeTxt;

    @View(R.id.locationNameTxt)
    private TextView locationNameTxt;

    private Profile mProfile;
    private Context mContext;
    private SwipePlaceHolderView mSwipeView;

    public TinderCard(Context context, Profile profile, SwipePlaceHolderView swipeView) {
        mContext = context;
        mProfile = profile;
        mSwipeView = swipeView;
    }

    @Resolve
    private void onResolved(){
        Glide.with(mContext).load(mProfile.getImageUrl()).into(profileImageView);
        nameAgeTxt.setText(mProfile.getName() + ", " + mProfile.getAge());
        locationNameTxt.setText(mProfile.getLocation());
    }

    @SwipeOut
    private void onSwipedOut(){
        Log.d("EVENT", "onSwipedOut");
        mSwipeView.addView(this);
    }

    @SwipeCancelState
    private void onSwipeCancelState(){
        Log.d("EVENT", "onSwipeCancelState");
    }

    @SwipeIn
    private void onSwipeIn(){
        Log.d("EVENT", "onSwipedIn");
    }

    @SwipeInState
    private void onSwipeInState(){
        Log.d("EVENT", "onSwipeInState");
    }

    @SwipeOutState
    private void onSwipeOutState(){
        Log.d("EVENT", "onSwipeOutState");
    }
}
```

This is the Xml file not sure whether anything is wrong here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profileImageView"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nameAgeTxt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Nikki, 18"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/locationNameTxt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="University of Albana"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                tools:ignore="TextSizeCheck" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

- I tried clearing the catch nothing
- I tried to rebuild the project nothing
- I created the new TinderCard.java still not working
- I created new file xml file nothing
- I removed this line of Code @Layout(R.layout.tinder_card_view) the error disappeared
- I searched on google YouTube nothing not sure why

what were you expecting?
To Show this layout tinder_card_view.xml from TinderCard

I apologies for poor language.
THANKS IN ADVANCE FOR YOUR HELP